# How can I load the mini Project?

Tags: android-studio

I want to open a mini project sent me by a friend, but I cant despite I change the local properties

There are two picture from android studio [image: enter image description here this is the first]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I provide a simple explanation by editing it using a yellow box from image you shared.

The first box is the location of Android Studio SDK your friend used. It looks `C:\Users\Emma\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk` as the directory.

The second one is the location of Android Studio SDK you are using. It Looks `C:\Users\Wael1\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`. Just click OK.

Then wait for Gradle to finish building. After all done, you should be able to run your friend's project on your computer.